# Config i18n-tasks is missing

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rails-i18n, i18n-tasks

I have just find this gem that will potentially save me a huge amount of time. 
https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks
I have installed it and start using it, the problem is that I can't find the
config/i18n-tasks.yml file, do I have to run some kind of initialize command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added this to [Readme](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks#configuration) today (works on v0.4.5+).

You can generate a config file with:

```bash
cp $(i18n-tasks gem-path)/templates/config/i18n-tasks.yml config/
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should create it by yourself & fill in with changed defaults, as the gem does not provide any by itself.

You can find all the possible configurations here https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks#configuration. This is pretty bad that it does not have any generator for Rails / Rack apps, but examples are pretty explanatory.